# Select of value range in a column with a single value removed from start and one added at the end

Tags: r, function, filter

I have a data frame like this

```
col1 = rnorm(1:100)  
col2 = c(1:100)  
col3 = c(501:600)  
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

I want to select 30 first values in col1 (i.e. row 1 to 30), do a simple calculation, then loop this to
select 30 values again from col1 (i.e. row 2 to 31), repeat this until I have last 30 row (to 71 to 100).
I can select with subset everytime (I know there are other ways to select subsamples)

I want to do something like this, but automated with a function or for-loop

```
df30 <- df[1:30,]  
df31 <- df[2:31,]  
df31 <- df[3:32,]
```

and so on

How can I do this in R? I appreciate your help

Comment: If you want to apply a function say `mean` `library(data.table); library(zoo);setDT(df)[, rollapply(col1, 30, mean)]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to take mean of the thirty values, I just want to have them in df30, df31, df32 etc. is there a way to do that?

Comment: Creating multiple objects in the global env is not recommended.  I am just showing a way to apply a function.  INstead of mean, you can apply your custom function in the rollapply

Comment: Thanks, I understand your point. OK, I don't want to create 71 objects, but is it possible to have df[1:30,] as a dataframe to run models on, then replicate this for the last 30 values?

Comment: If you need subset, just do `lst <-  lapply(1:(nrow(df)-30 + 1), function(i) df[i:(i+29),])` create a list.  within in the `list` you can run your models for each dataset

Comment: It worked well, many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to work out better if you assemble these results in a named list, rather than making a collection of unconnected objects in you global workspace: First make a list of subsets and then add the names:

```
dflist <- lapply(1:71, function(n) df[n:(n+30), ] )
names(dflist) <- paste0("df", 30:100)
```

You will then be able to loop over these with the `lapply` function or even use a for loop since they have an order as well as being named internally.